# JavaScript Error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js

I am trying to use Chart JS in one of my laravel applications.

I am pushing the data through the route and using json_encode($gross) to echo the gross of each order by day but I am getting the following error in my console log:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

It references the the line of where I have used json_encode($gross). Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

```
Here is the code coming through the controller:

public function index()
{   $wkRevenue = \App\Order::where('created_at', '>=' , \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())->get();
    // dd($wkRevenue->pluck('created_at','gross'));

    return view('admin.dashboard')
            ->with('created_at', $wkRevenue->pluck('created_at'))
            ->with('grosss', $wkRevenue->pluck('gross'));
}

Here is the code in the js file:

var data = {
    type:'line',
    labels:['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun'],
    datasets:[
    {
        data: {!! json_encode($gross) !!},
        backgroundColor:'rgba(137, 200, 85, 0.4)',
    }
]
}
var graph = document.getElementById('myNewChart').getContext('2d');
var myNewChart = new Chart(graph ,{
type: "line",
data: data,
options:{
    title:{
        display:true,
    }
}
});
```

Comment: It means you have a syntax error.  If you post your code maybe I can identify it for you.

Comment: The string `$gross` is probably not a valid JSON. Try printing that string and confirm.

Comment: Please post your code or part of it so we can see what is happening exactly

Comment: You can't echo JSON directly into a `<script>` tag and have it work. Show an example of the rendered code.

Comment: I have never seen this exclaimation marks before `!! json_encode($gross) !!`, do they allow you to write php code in javascript? if yes then you just need `echo`

Comment: @TheFlash welcome to Laravel

Comment: @TheFlash this is Laravel syntax for not escaping strings (it's a wrapper for echo). Like Mike McCaghan said, please post the rendered output of `{!! json_encode($gross) !!}`. Go to the page where you get the console error, view source (ctrl + u) and find the output and paste it here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your controller:

```
->with('grosss', $wkRevenue->pluck('gross'));
```

needs to be:

```
->with('gross', $wkRevenue->pluck('gross'));
```

Laravel [changed the `pluck()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#collections) in 5.2 to return a collection instead of an array.

In your view change your `json_encode()` to:

```
{!! $gross->toJson() !!}
```